# Save Spark dataframe as parquet file in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I am trying to save a Spark dataframe to Google Cloud Storage. We are able to save the dataframe in parquet format to S3, but because our server is Google Compute Engine, there will be a huge data transfer cost to S3. I would like if it's possible to have similar function for Google Cloud Storage? Below is what I did in case of S3:

Add dependencies to build.sbt:

```
"net.java.dev.jets3t" % "jets3t" % "0.9.4",
"com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.10.16"
```

Use this in the main code:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", conf.getString("s3.awsAccessKeyId"))
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", conf.getString("s3.awsSecretAccessKey"))

val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3a://.../*") //read file
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(s3FileName) //write file
```

And finally, use this with spark-submit

```
spark-submit --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem 
--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem
```

I tried to look for a similar guide in the internet, but there doesn't seems to have one? Could any one please suggest me how I can get it done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone wants to do the same thing, I got this working as follows:

Add library dependency to SBT:

```
"com.google.cloud.bigdataoss" % "gcs-connector" % "1.4.2-hadoop2"
```

Set the Hadoop configuration:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.project.id", conf.getString("gcs.projectId"))
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.email", conf.getString("gcs.serviceAccountEmail"))
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.keyfile", conf.getString("gcs.serviceAccountKeyFile"))
```

Then you can save and read the file like you would for S3. The only thing is that it's not working with Spark 1.4 at the time I tested, so you might want to update it to Spark 1.5+ instead.

Comment: What is `conf` supposed to be?

Comment: @BAR: It's typesafe config from application.conf

Comment: I know it's kind of obvious it's an external config, but you should specify it anyways.

Comment: Did it work for you in Spark 1.5?  I ask as I think it'll only work in 1.3 and before due to the way the "live" hadoopConfiguration is ignored by SparkHadoopUtil.